# I only get 1 row out of 50 when query Mysql database usinh PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I´m having a weird issue using PHP to query Mysql database. When I try the following:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT art_date FROM arts_dates WHERE prod_id = '$prod'");
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$number_of_results = count($row);
```

It outputs just the first row out of 50 (I checked using var_dump, and try other combination like `SELECT *`). When I ran the exact same query on phpMyAdmin, it shows me the 50 results.

What could be happening?

Answer (score 3):

You are only seeing a single row because you are *asking* for a single row, that is what `fetch()` method does.

To retrieve all rows from the statement at once you would need to use [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

Comment: Thanks! I missed that!